# Assistance in fixing the performance time of algorithmn

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, pairwise

The following program is created to perform a pair-wise election over a rank ordered set of ballots.

the end result is to have the pair-wise election completes all test cases in under .01s of elapsed execution time.

Currently the program end result time performance is at about .02 secs.
Need assistance to help lower the time to .01 seconds and less.

Below is the program code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * 
 * 
 *         Utility class to compute the pairwise winner of elections
 */
public class PairwiseVote {
    /**
     * Get the placement order of a candidate in a rank order list of candidates
     *
     * @param votersVotes
     *            an array of rank order candidates. First has the highest rank.
     */
    public static int getPlacement(int candidate, int[] votersVotes) {
        for (int placement = 0; placement < votersVotes.length; placement++) {
            if (candidate == votersVotes[placement]) {
                return placement;
            }
        }
        return votersVotes.length + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the candidate winner from a set of rank ordered ballots
     *
     * @param votes
     *            - a two dimensional array, first dimension is the voter, second
     *            dimension is the rank ordered ballot of candidates for the given
     *            voter
     */
    public static int getPairwiseWinner(int[][] votes) {
        int noVoters = votes.length;

        if (noVoters == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int noCandidates = votes[0].length;

        if (noCandidates == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        // Compare every pair of candidates
        for (int candidate1 = 0; candidate1 < noCandidates; candidate1++) {
            int noTimesCandidate1Wins = 0;
            for (int candidate2 = 0; candidate2 < noCandidates; candidate2++) {
                // Consider a candidate compared with themselves to be a winner
                if (candidate1 == candidate2) {
                    noTimesCandidate1Wins++;
                    continue;
                }

                // Determine count the ballots for each candidate
                int candidate1votes = 0;
                int candidate2votes = 0;
                for (int voter = 0; voter < noVoters; voter++) {
                    int placement1 = getPlacement(candidate1, votes[voter]);
                    int placement2 = getPlacement(candidate2, votes[voter]);
                    if (placement1 < placement2) {
                        candidate1votes++;
                        ;
                    } else {
                        candidate2votes++;
                        ;
                    }
                }

                // determine if candidate1 is the winner if so increment the number of wins
                if (candidate1votes > candidate2votes) {
                    noTimesCandidate1Wins++;
                }
            }

            // Determine if candidate 1 wins all
            if (noTimesCandidate1Wins == noCandidates) {
                return candidate1;
            }
        }

        // No winner
        return -1;
    }

    static int electionNo = 0;

    /**
     * Main - reads several test elections using the text file votes.txt. Each
     * election begins with two number, the number of voters and the number of
     * candidates, all followed by the ballots of each voter.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int noVoters;
        int noCandidates;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("votes.txt"));

        // read ballots for each election
        for (;;) {
            noVoters = in.nextInt();
            noCandidates = in.nextInt();

            if (noVoters == 0 && noCandidates == 0) {
                break;
            }

            final int[][] votes = new int[noVoters][noCandidates];

            // Read the ballots
            for (int i = 0; i < noVoters; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < noCandidates; j++) {
                    votes[i][j] = in.nextInt();
                }
            }

            new TimeExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int winner = getPairwiseWinner(votes);
                    if (winner >= 0) {
                        System.out.printf("Winner of election %d is candidate %d\n", electionNo, winner);
                    } else {
                        System.out.printf("No winner for election %d\n", electionNo);
                    }
                }
            }, "Election " + ++electionNo, System.out).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You can first which code costs more time then to do some work to reduce time consuming.

Comment: @TongChen i don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current code is calling to getPlacement `noCandidates*noCandidates*noVoters*2` times but it would be enough to call it `noCandidates*noVoters` times.

You can manage that by precalculating values and storing them like this (not sure if it's compiling as I don't program on java, but I guess you can get the idea):

```
public static int getPairwiseWinner(int[][] votes) {
    int noVoters = votes.length;

    if (noVoters == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int noCandidates = votes[0].length;

    if (noCandidates == 0) {

        return -1;
    }

    int[][] placements = new int[noVoters][noCandidates]; // to store precalculated placements

    // go through each of the voters and precalculate the placements of each candidate
    for (int voter = 0; voter<noVoters; voter++) {

        for (int candidate = 0; candidate < noCandidates; candidate++) {

            placements[voter][candidate] = getPlacement(candidate, votes[voter]);
        }
    }

    // Compare every pair of candidates
    for (int candidate1 = 0; candidate1 < noCandidates; candidate1++) {

        int noTimesCandidate1Wins = 0;
        for (int candidate2 = 0; candidate2 < noCandidates; candidate2++) {

            // Consider a candidate compared with themselves to be a winner
            if (candidate1 == candidate2) {

                noTimesCandidate1Wins++;
                continue;
            }

            // Determine count the ballots for each candidate
            int candidate1votes = 0;
            int candidate2votes = 0;
            for (int voter = 0; voter < noVoters; voter++) {

                // use precalculated placements
                if (placements[voter][candidate1] < placements[voter][candidate2]) {

                    candidate1votes++;
                    ;
                } else {


                    candidate2votes++;
                    ;
                }
            }

            // determine if candidate1 is the winner if so increment the number of wins
            if (candidate1votes > candidate2votes) {

                noTimesCandidate1Wins++;
            }
        }

        // Determine if candidate 1 wins all
        if (noTimesCandidate1Wins == noCandidates) {

            return candidate1;
        }
    }

    // No winner
    return -1;
}
```